# Regex: Parse anchor character in a regex parser

Tags: regex, parsing, syntax, compiler-construction

I am trying to develop a regex parser, and I could not figure out how to handle the anchor character (`$`) in my recursive descent parser.

Here is the BNF I have:

```
 * regex    = "^" regex
            | regex "$"
            | term ( "|" term)*
 * term     = concat concat*

 * concat   = element [*]
 *          | element [+]
 *          | element [?]
 *          | element "{" int* "}"
 *          | element "{" int* "," "}"
 *          | element "{" int* "," int* "}"
 * element  = "(" regex")" | escaped_char | range | int | metacharacter | char
 * ranges   = "[" range* "]"
 * range    =  char "-" char         
 * metacharacter = ...
 * escaped_char = ...
 * int = 0 .. 9
 * char = ascii char
```

**More specifically, how can I handle `$` with only one lookahead?**

The last `concat` node needs to be capture by the `$` sign, is it possible to handle it in a recursive descent parser ? Or I might need to use other parsing algorithm?

What I have in mind is this (with some comment if it helps to clear my question) :

```
function parse_term token_list : (ast * token_list) = 
    next_token = lookahead token_list

    if next_token is '^'
        consume_tok ()
        anchor_group = parse_concat token_list

        if next_token is in follow_set(concat)
            consume_tok ()
            concat1 =  parse_concat token_list

            while next_token is in follow_set(concat)
                consume_tok ()
                concat1 = construct_concat (concat1, parse_concat token_list)

            return construct_concat (anchor_group, concat1)

        else 
            return anchor_group

    else if next_token is in follow_set(concat):

        concat1 =  parse_concat token_list

        while next_token is in follow_set(concat)
            consume_tok ()
            concat1 = construct_concat (concat1, parse_concat token_list)

        ------------------------------------------------
        here I need to handle the $ metacharacter for the last concat node
        but it has been handled in the while loop already.
        ----------------------------------------------------
        ....
```

Comment: Your problem arises from the fact that your premise is wrong: unless you want to recognize a very restrictive subset of common regex patterns, anchors are allowed anywhere in the pattern, and `$` could match multiple times in a single string when used along with a modifier such as *multiline*. I'd just add it as another `element`. Same thing for ranges, that's overkill - something like `[:-@]` should be valid.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Hi, I updated my BNF grammar. Do you mind take another look and see if my premise is correct now?

Comment: I meant you should do something like `element  = "(" regex")" | escaped_char | range | int | metacharacter | char | "^" | "$"` as a pattern such as `^^^foo$$$` is valid and equivalent to `^foo$`. Likewise `^foo$\s*^bar$` is valid and will match `foo` and `bar` separated with newlines.